# Strange speeds of `x in range(...)` checks

Tags: python, performance, range

With `r = range(1500, 2500)`, I benchmarked `x in r` for `x` below/in/above the range:

```
1000 in r :   58 ns ± 0 ns
2000 in r :  101 ns ± 1 ns
3000 in r :   58 ns ± 0 ns
```

Checking 1000 is faster than checking 2000? Makes sense, as for 1000, Python knows the result after only checking the range's *lower* bound, whereas for 2000 it needs to check *both* bounds.

Checking 3000 is faster than checking 2000? Makes sense, as for 3000, Python knows the result after only checking the range's *upper* bound, whereas for 2000 it needs to check *both* bounds.

Hey... waaaiiit a minute...

How does it know which bound to check first? How can 1000 and 3000 *both* be checked faster than 2000?

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBRasMwDP33KfQTHIfAkmWDLZCTlDKyRtn8YcfY6mgpO9SusItlktMWpg8h3tN7enY40@fiu5cQ13WOiwOyDi2BdWGJBBEDjqQyk2gkm8ge0o11OPqa8Qm/lEpIxwAD6Mgtjv4Dy/a5aWp45G60Up7xtqmqJzUvEd7A@utaZ3oFXAKfBG6brMu9477RUodlQraZ9eX0nQ30naIkd3PeUtY4mCSqwR/dO8aBk27swPbmv2xHDx4qaPE1hyCxTvxCnEpKZte3zX5/V4Ro/e2E7gGKbgKf4PcHChk0FFDKz4j0@jsymu3mpjbr@gc)):

```
from timeit import repeat
from statistics import mean, stdev

setup = 'r = range(1500, 2500)'

n = 10**4
for _ in range(3):
    for x in 1000, 2000, 3000:
        code = f'{x} in r'
        ts = repeat(code, setup, number=n, repeat=100)
        ts = [t/n * 1e9 for t in sorted(ts)[:10]]
        print(code, ':  %3d ns ± %d ns' % (mean(ts), stdev(ts)))
    print()
```

Comment: It's almost certainly just checking `if 1500 <= x < 2500:`. The Python compiler decides which order to check.

Comment: @Barmar That explanation disagrees with the times. As discussed in the question. (Also, it's not true.)

Comment: What's the value to investigating undefined behavior (insofar as the language doesn't define performance expectations for these operations)? There's no guarantee that the answer will be true in future interpreter releases. It's important to know what the big-O guarantees are on how code will scale, but if you need to know what the trivial constant factors are, it's probably time to move to a language where those _are_ well-defined (even if in the sense of "guaranteed to compile down to, and have performance of, specific assembly instructions").

Comment: Python is open-source, you can easily look at how it's implemented.

Comment: This could answer some questions (or pose new ones): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/rangeobject.c

Comment: The [;10] looks fishy. What does that do? Only look at the 10 slowest runs?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Curiosity, figuring out why the above theory is wrong, and getting reminded about a certain aspect.

Comment: @Sören The ten *fastest*. The doc for `repeat` suggests to just take the minimum, but I prefer to look at a few more and their stdev, then I know better whether the machine happened to give me a stable run.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, looking up the code was the next thing I did.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That certain aspect being the step/stride. I suspected I wouldn't be the only one forgetting about that. And judging by the votes for chepner's answer, I believe I was correct in deeming this interesting enough to share.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CPython, the implementation first checks the value against *both* endpoints:

```
if (cmp1 == 1) { /* positive steps: start <= ob < stop */
    cmp2 = PyObject_RichCompareBool(r->start, ob, Py_LE);
    cmp3 = PyObject_RichCompareBool(ob, r->stop, Py_LT);
}
```

If either is false, it can exit immediately:

```
if (cmp2 == 0 || cmp3 == 0) { /* ob outside of range */
    result = 0;
    goto end;
}
```

If both checks are true, though, it then has to check if the stride rejects the value. (For example, `2000 in range(1501, 2500)` is true, but `2000 in range(1501, 2500, 2)` is false.)

```
tmp1 = PyNumber_Subtract(ob, r->start);
if (tmp1 == NULL)
    goto end;
tmp2 = PyNumber_Remainder(tmp1, r->step);
if (tmp2 == NULL)
    goto end;
/* result = ((int(ob) - start) % step) == 0 */
result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(tmp2, zero, Py_EQ);
```

It's this last step that makes `2000 in range(1500, 2500)` slower than either out-of-bound check.

(See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/rangeobject.c#L381 for the full implementation.)

Comment: I'm surprised that there's no special case for stride=1.

Comment: Maybe the `(ob - start) % stride` for `stride=1` is cheap enough it's not worth adding a branch to avoid

Comment: I think the current implementation is simpler (and possibly not significantly slower) than the code needed to determine *which* special case (stride 1 for increasing ranges, stride -1 for decreasing ranges) to check.

Comment: Or, such a change isn't a big enough improvement to convince the developers to accept a pull request :)

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the CPython implementation, we can see that the [`range_contains_long`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/rangeobject.c#L406) function does indeed contain a quick bounds check, specialized for both positive and negative steps.

This explains why the outer cases are both much faster, but of course, it's specific to a single implementation and could change at any time.